# BOOL gives different result in if statement at update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime method

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, boolean, skscene

I have two scenes - `DifficultScene` and `GameScene`. In `DifficultScene` I have three buttons - easy, medium and hard. I use a global variable Bool to keep track of the current difficulty level. When I try easy mode everything works fine, but when I try medium or hard, bool is changing every second, jumping from hard to medium and easy, making game unplayable. **My question is - how can I fix it?** Here are code were it happens:
**GamesScene.m**

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */
extern BOOL isEasyMode;
extern BOOL isMediumMode;
extern BOOL isHardMode;
if ((isEasyMode = YES)) {
    NSLog(@"easy");
    [self computer];
}
if ((isMediumMode = YES)) {
    NSLog(@"medium");
    [self computerMedium];
}
if ((isHardMode = YES)) {
    NSLog(@"hard");
    [self computerHard];
}

[self scoreCount];
}
```

(if more code is needed, i will post it)

Comment: Do you mean `if (a == b)`: double "="? And you don't seem to set them. But You may be interested in a enum rather than 3 bool?

Comment: @Larme thank you for your response, but Iam kinda new to objective c and i don't know how to use enum, if its not hard can you show it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your update method calls periodically as per timer so it will get called continuously if it so then. Thats why it is happening i think and another major thing is you should use `==` for comparison. you are using `(isEasyMode = YES)` that means you are assigning `YES` to `isEasyMode`.

So replce all if statement like `if ((isEasyMode = YES))` with `if (isEasyMode == YES)`.

**Update :**

if statement should like,

```
  if (isEasyMode == YES) {
    NSLog(@"easy");
    [self computer];
}
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: thank you for your response, but it didn't work for me, it gave me warning "Equality comparison with extraneous parentheses"

Comment: I think you have done mistake, your if statement should like,  if (isEasyMode == YES) {
        NSLog(@"easy");
       // [self computer];   
    }

Comment: Check update in answer also and remove `extern` before `bool`

Comment: well it kind of works, if I remove `extern` then it doesn't work, but besides that, code works. thank you

Comment: you're welcome... :) If you feel that it is helpful then up vote the answer :)